# Create symbolic links after building using CMAKE

Tags: cmake, ninja, cmakelists-options

I want a `add_custom_target` to run a loop over some files to create several symbolic links (and maybe doing more stuff).

My approach (maybe not the best?) has been:

```
add_custom_target(myTargetNAme-link  echo "HERE" # This is printed
  COMMAND
  for file in /mylocation/*
  do
    ### Create links using $file
  done
  DEPENDS dependency
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMENT "Create a link to use files in dev env" VERBATIM
)
```

And I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

- Is this a smart way to do operations over files?
- What's the right syntax for a foor loop like this in CMAKE?

**EDIT**

Following the comment in the question,  I'd like to be more precise:

I have a project that produces a `.so` file containing a python module AND it should come with a couple `.py` files.

What I *really* want to do is to create a symbolic link from the `.so` and `.py` files to the python installation.

I was reusing some code, these targets were called in a script using:

```
nice -n 11 ninja myTargetNAme-link
```

Maybe I could avoid doing this as well?

**ALSO**

I deleted the `VERBATIM` keyword and it made it possible to use `*.py` for `ln` so now the symbolic link are actually generated.

Comment: The best approach depends on what you're _actually_ doing. If you can post a full example and explain what it does versus what you want it to do, we can help you better.

Comment: It's also _highly suspicious_ that you're writing anything to `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`. I promise there's a better way.

Comment: if you want to write something that also works on windows, you'll need a different approach. I'd recommend writing a cmake script and calling it in the `COMMAND` with `${CMAKE_COMMAND} "-D arg1=${value_of_arg1}" "-D arg2=${value_of_arg2}" "-P" "${path_to_script}"`.

Comment: @AlexReinking I added a lot of new info. I hope it's clear.